# Python set a variable not working

Tags: python, variables

I am new to python and I have this script to set a variable:

```
set python = 1
print (python)
```

I have tried this

```
set (python) = 1
print (python)
```

But this doesn't seem to work ether. Can any one help.

Comment: `set <variable name> = <expression>` is **not** Python syntax. Remove it altogether.

Comment: Where did you learn this? o.O

Comment: @09stephenb: it says `spam = 5` there. *Not* `set spam = 5`. There is prose that uses the verb 'to set' to describe what happens.

Comment: Who in the world upvotes this question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Python. In Python, to set a variable, use:

```
name = 1
```

And reassign:

```
name = [1, 2, 3]
```

EDIT:

The [exercise](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-python-6WeG3/0/2?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) asks you to set the variable `my_variable` to `10`.

So use:

```
my_variable = 10 # set my_variable to 10, and use your brain
```

Comment: Thanks it seams I getting some python and batch mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write set. Its not a python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed and creates objects as it goes along. You don't really have constants or anything along those lines (at least at a beginners level - I'm not sure about advanced levels but I doubt it).

As a result whenever you declare a variable just input:

`RandomVariableName = 1`

or

`RandomVariableName = "one"`

Python will automatically figure out what the type of object is and assign it to that name (loosely speaking).